# Build Task VSBuild@1 not building .Net Framework 4 Web application (aspx) correctly

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I'm trying to configure ci/cd for an old project which uses `.net framework 4` and is `aspx` pages web app. I'm using `VSBuild@1` task to build it with following config:

[image]

It builds it correctly. But the problem is that it places the `/App_GlobalResources` on root level as well. Whereas when I publish it locally on my Visual Studio, it doesn't generate this folder at all. Hence when I try to deploy the `artifact` produced from VSBuild@1 task, it gives following error, and application won't start/run:

> The directory '/App_GlobalResources/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled

If I remove this folder manually from deployed folder on server, the application works fine. But the newly added resources in `.resx` files are not compiled. i.e, they are not there at all, hence application will crash whenever trying to access such resource key.

**Question**: How can I fix this problem? The build task should produce such an artifact which should not include /App_GlobalResources folder in main level. And that resource files inside that should also be built.

*(I have encountered this type of error for first time, may be I wasn't able to explain well, so any questions are welcome, I'll provide more details accordingly)*

Answer (score 0):

```
The directory '/App_GlobalResources/' is not allowed because the application is precompiled
```

Above error is a common problem caused by the precompiled site. You can try to delete the `PrecompiledApp.config` file and re-start your application.

Here is a [case](https://forums.asp.net/t/1976351.aspx?App_GlobalResources%20is%20not%20allowed%20because%20the%20application%20is%20precompiled%20publishing%20website%20in%20vss%202012) with similar issue you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I saw that post already. But I did not want to remove `Precompiled.config`. Correct me if I'm wrong, it will decrease the performance to some degrees, and I don't think it's a good trade off to compromise performance just for automatic deployment.